# Highcharts swipe smooth move feature

Tags: jquery, highcharts, swipe

I plotted the graph using highcharts. I have 12 tickers on x axis. but default (onload) I show only first 6 using highcharts option **min, max**. I have next button to show the reset of graph using **setExtremes(6, 11)**. I works all good. But Now I am looking for the same feature on touch swipe (mobile & web). I can't find any attached event on plugin to do that stuff. Does anyone tried the same! Can someone tell some possible ways to do that. Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gchoken/sdoftjr8/) to play around!

```
$(function () {

    var xCategories = ["06:30AM", "08:30AM", "10:30AM", "12:30PM", "02:30PM", "04:30PM", "06:30PM", "08:30PM", "10:30PM", "12:30AM", "02:30AM", "04:30AM"];
    var alerts_temp_graph = $('#alerts_temp_graph').highcharts({
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        chart: {
            //zoomType: 'x',
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            type: 'spline',
        },
        title: {
            text: '',
            x: 0 //center
        },
        xAxis: [{
            gridLineWidth: 0.5,
            startOnTick: false,
            endOnTick: false,
            minPadding: 0,
            maxPadding: 0,
            tickInterval: 1,
            labels: {
                //rotation:-90,
                formatter: function () {
                    return xCategories[this.value];
                }
            },
            min: 0,
            max: 6,
            plotBands: [{
                "color": "",
                    "to": 0,
                    "from": 0.5
            }, {
                "color": "#fcf8e8",
                    "to": 0.5,
                    "from": 1
            }, {
                "color": "#fcf8e8",
                    "to": 1,
                    "from": 1.5
            }, {
                "color": "#fcf8e8",
                    "to": 1.5,
                    "from": 2
            }, {
                "color": "",
                    "to": 2,
                    "from": 2.5
            }, {
                "color": "",
                    "to": 2.5,
                    "from": 3
            }, {
                "color": "",
                    "to": 3,
                    "from": 3.5
            }, {
                "color": "",
                    "to": 3.5,
                    "from": 4
            }, {
                "color": "",
                    "to": 4,
                    "from": 4.5
            }, {
                "color": "",
                    "to": 4.5,
                    "from": 5
            }, {
                "color": "",
                    "to": 5,
                    "from": 5.5
            }],
        }],
        yAxis: [{
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            }

        }],

        plotOptions: {
            spline: {
                lineWidth: 4,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 5
                    }
                },
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                }

            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        legend: false,

        series: [{
            lineWidth: 8,
            color: '#24d3c4',
            data: [60.93, 57.75, 56.58, 55.62, 54.79, 53.83, 60.93, 57.75, 56.58, 55.62, 54.79, 53.83],


        }]
    });



    $(document).on('click', '#next', function () {

        var alerts_temp_graph = $('#alerts_temp_graph').highcharts();
        alerts_temp_graph.xAxis[0].setExtremes(6, 11);


    });

});
```

Comment: Have you tried to enable [panning](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.panning)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but you might need to have [***`touchmove`***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchmove) event:

```
$(document).on('touchmove', function () {
    var alerts_temp_graph = $('#alerts_temp_graph').highcharts();
    alerts_temp_graph.xAxis[0].setExtremes(6, 11);
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sdoftjr8/1/)

Tested on chrome <sup>*version: 39.0.2171.95 (Official Build) m*</sup> with **toggle device mode[1]**.
<sub>[1] -- The small mobile icon in the chrome inspector toolbar.</sub>

Comment: Jai thanks for pointing this, but can we detect direction of swipe (left,right,top, down) on touchmove function?